# Flutter - Calculate Sum and Percentage of total items in a list

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble calculating the sum and percentage of items in the list:

```
list = [
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 3), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 35),
GenderAgeView(gender: U, total: 1), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 45), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 65), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 1), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 8), 
GenderAgeView(gender: U, total: 1), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 43), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 50), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 31), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 16), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 36), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 50), 
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 23)
]
```

EDIT - I want to retrieve the dataPoints() method.
I want to group and calculate the sum and percentage... The output should look like this:

```
GenderAgeView(gender: M, total: 120), 
GenderAgeView(gender: F, total: 100),
GenderAgeView(gender: U, total: 2)
```

What I have done so far:

```
List<GenderAgeView> dataPoints() {
    // var data is my main list I get the data from the API call
    var data = genderAgeControllerData.genderAgeList;
    // Here I create a list and check if for null empty values on attribute gender
    var list = data.where((m) => m.gender != '').map<GenderAgeView>((m) {
      return GenderAgeView(
        gender: m.gender,
        total: m.total,
      );
    }).toList();

    return list;
  }
```

I am not sure if I have to use reduce to sum and then divide by the length of the list...

Please, can you assist? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the desired output in `dataPoints()` method?

Comment: @MoazEl-sawaf oh yeah... sorry. Yes, that's correct - editing my question

Comment: I am also trying with Map: ```Map map = Map();
    for (var gen in list) {
      if (map.keys.contains(gen.gender)) {
        map[gen.gender] = map[gen.gender] + gen.total;
      } else
        map[gen.gender] = gen.total;
    }
    print(map.toString()); ``` wrong output: {M: 345651503623, F: 35843311650, U: 11}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the https://pub.dev/packages/collection package from pub.dev. I imported it using:

`import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Then use this bit of code. The `groupBy` creates a map with the keys being the gender and the entry being a list of `GenderAgeViews`. Then, you iterate over every key in the map and add a `GenderAgeView` object to the `resultList`. The `fold` method then takes all entries and counts the total of every one of them, which is then used in the constructor.

```
List<GenderAgeView> dataPoints() {
  List<GenderAgeView> data = genderAgeControllerData.genderAgeList;
  final groupedMap = col.groupBy(data, (GenderAgeView data) => data.gender);
  List resultList = [];
  groupedMap.forEach((key, entries) {
    resultList.add(GenderAgeView(gender: key, total: entries.fold(0, (total,cur) => total + cur.total)));
  });
  return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Note that this does group by keys, so you have to guarantee that all keys are correct.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I've spent lots of time on it and you saved my day. Thank you very much Lars.